# Sending Error Messages to Another Page?

Tags: php

When a user creates their own account, if there is an error I want to redirect them to the same page but display the errors at the top.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why the redirect? Why don’t your just print the error? Use a template if you want to separate the data processing from the data output.

Comment: Because if a user is filling in the input boxes and they enter the wrong information, when they press "register" I want them to be redirected to the registration page and told about the error.

Comment: Just send the form data to the same page and do the validation there before outputting the form. Then you can print an error and fill the form.

Answer (score 3):

Structure your page as follows (in rough pseudo-code)

```
if (doing a post) {
    process input
    if (post is ok) {
       redirect to success page
    } else {
       build error messages
    }
}

if (error messages available) {
    display errors
}

display form(filled in with previously submitted values)
```

Comment: That's what I do, but is there a way to do this without combining PHP and HTMl in the same page

Comment: sure, use a templating system. but no matter what kind of template system you're using, at SOME point, code/html have to get mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

i like to create a function named `set_feedback()` that sets the error in a session variable. then i have this other function `get_feedback()` that retrieves the information and unset the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I save the error into the session and remove it once it was rendered. As you will probably abort the pages execution on a redirect it will never reach the code responsible for rendering thus leaving it in the session.